# 手にする usage? Is it a version of 手にいれる？

Tags: meaning, word-choice

How is 手にする used? Does it mean the same thing as 手に入{い}れる, or is there a difference between them?

For example, in this line from a show:

> 心と体が今、一つに！地球を手にした究極の(fictional char name)。

Would it be different with 手に入れる instead?

I checked [the definition for 手にする in the Progressive J-E dictionary](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E6%89%8B%E3%81%AB%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B/#je-50666), but one of the examples is for having it literally in your hand and the other seems the same as 手に入れる for obtaining things. So I'm still confused as to the differences.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the dictionary, 手にする has two meanings: 「(手に)持つ」"have/hold (in one's hand)" and 「手に入れる」"win, gain, obtain".

In your example, it's used in the latter meaning. So you can rephrase it this way:

> 「地球を**手にした**究極のXX.」
>   「地球を**手に入れた**究極のXX.」

The difference between the two is, I think 手にする sounds more formal and literary while 手に入れる is neutral and more commonly used.